# Basic multiple if statement logic flow syntax in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, if-statement

I can't seem to understand how to continue to another IF statement. What I'm trying to do is:

- IF Action 1 succeed then do X AND go to Action 2, else log it and RETURN to the next loop
- If Action 2 succeed then do X AND go to Action 3, else log it and RETURN to the next loop

I am having issues with "AND go to Action 2" after action 1. I tried various ways but obviously the script below does not work. It can do Action 1 the test-connection, and if it succeeds will export the log else it will log a failure and RETURN to the next loop. HOWEVER, I cannot make it do the next action if successful.

```
$hostname = Import-Csv C:\Users\jackie.cheng\Desktop\TestComputers.csv

$hostname | % {

if (Test-Connection $_.hostname -count 1)

{Write-Host "$($_.hostname) Test-Connection Succeeded"
            $array += [pscustomobject]@{
                Name = $currentobject.hostname
                Status = "Test-Connection Success"}
}

else  {Write-Host "$($_.hostname) Test-Connection Failed"
            $array2 += [pscustomobject]@{
                Name = $currentobject.hostname
                Status = "Failed Test-Connection"}
       } return

if (Test-Connection $_.hostname -count 1)

{Write-Host "Second action ran"}

else {Write-Host "Second action failed"} return


}
```

Comment: What is `$currentobject.hostname` supposed to be?

Comment: That's just something I was doing in the catch. I had to rename $currentobject = $_. I will edit that.

Comment: You are thinking in a legacy VB/BAT GOTO mindset. There is no GOTO in PS, though can simulate it. [There are several docs you can find on the web](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=%27powershell+goto%27&t=h_&ia=web). You should also refresh your mindset on the [Return](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=%27powershell+retunr+keyword%27&t=h_&ia=web) keyword when used with PowerShell.

Comment: Both returns run every time outside of the if/else's.  You usually don't need return at all.  And why do two test-connections in the same loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within the script block of a `Foreach-Object`, which is the full name of the command with the alias `%`, you can in fact use return to skip any statements after the return, and continue on to the next loop.

In your case you simply need to move your `return` into your `else` blocks like this:

```
If (Success Condition){
   Actions to do on success
}
else{
   Actions to do on fail
   return
}

If (Success Condition 2){
   ...
}
else{
   ...
   return 
}
```

As mentioned in the comments to your question, be sure to read up on how `return` works in PowerShell as it is somewhat unusual and behaves differently in different contexts.

Comment: Yes, it was this simple! I had the return statement outside, so it never went to the 2nd if statement. Thank you so much! I have marked this as answered from you!

Answer (score 0):

I would do it this way, just output the objects for either case.  Notice the indenting to help see the structure of the code.  Return is usually not needed. -ea 0 means "-erroraction silentlycontinue".

```
Import-Csv TestComputers.csv |
% {
  if (Test-Connection $_.hostname -count 1 -ea 0) {
    [pscustomobject]@{
      Name = $_.hostname
      Status = $true}
  }
  else {
    [pscustomobject]@{
      Name = $_.hostname
      Status = $false}
  }
}


Name          Status
----          ------
yahoo.com       True
microsoft.com  False
```